# Is http connection-oriented?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory

I know the http is stateless protocol? but HTTP uses TCP which is connection-oriented protocol. so can I say http is a connection-oriented and stateless protocol?

Comment: Sadly, questions related to school assignments are off topic; questions about TCP payloads are off topic as well

Comment: HTTP doesn't always use TCP. Not all protocols are divided neatly into connection oriented or connectionless. See what should have been your first stop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: You could say that HTTP is a stateless protocol and that TCP is a connection oriented protocol.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP` is not a transport protocol like `TCP` or `UDP`. It operates on higher layers of the `ISO/OSI` model.

Thus there is no connection that can be set up.

Comment: is that means the http is connectionless protocol?

Comment: Neither connection-oriented nor connectionless since it does not set up a connection. The connection is built by Layer 4 protocols.